# RowIDs resetting in jqGrid,How to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

For some reason the rowIDs get reset once i do any any action from the pagination(increase the number of rows,move to next page etc)

for e.g i have 75records in total.Im displaying 15records at a time.In total i have 3 pages each can display 15records.When im in first page which is displaying that records from 1-15 i get rowIDs 1-15 for rows.Now when i move to next page which displays records from 16-30 i get the rowIDs 1-15 for rows.Here when i moved to new page where 16-30 records are being displayed i was expecting the rowIDs to be from 16-30 but they are not,they are from 1-15.Same thing happens when i do an action from pager to display 30 records at a time instead of 15(default).

I want rowID starting from 1 to n number of records instead of 1-15 for each page.Is there a way to do it? If yes than please help me out.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row Id will work this way because it generates dynamic Ids for your rows when your data is populated in the grid. This is the default behavior.

You can get a unique row Id if you set a Primary key. this way, you'll get the value of Primary key as row Id. Simply set `key: true` property of the column you want to set as primary key, in the `colModel` collection.

Comment: thanks for the reply.The reason why i wanted unique rowIDs is to fetch the data afterwards based on the rowIDs.If i have my own column of unique IDs,how will it help me to fetch the data of the row based on this unique ID? thanks

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand what you just said. If I understand it correctly, you need a unique ID to fetch data. The primary key on your Table 'is' the best possible unique key you would ever need

Comment: i was doing var pdProduct = $("#covlist").jqGrid('getCell', rowID,'mfgPartNo'); to fetch the data until i ran to the problem with rowIDs.Now if i have my own column of unique Keys will i be able to do something like var pdProduct = $("#covlist").jqGrid('getCell', uniqueKey,'mfgPartNo'); ?? this is my question.If i cant do this than is there any other way to fetch the data based on the unique keys column that i add?! thanks

Comment: in short is there any way to fetch the data which doesnt involve unstilizing rowIDs? thanks

Comment: You can continue to use `$("#covlist").jqGrid('getCell', rowID,'mfgPartNo');` . The solution I have posted will solve your problem of repeating Ids

Comment: @Obi-WanSpock I am using rowId as primary key for the same situation in the question because my grid does not have primary key. Is there a way to force the row Id from not being reset.