# Prevent RowIds from resetting on sorting, paging or deleting rows

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid version 4.6.0

My question is the same as
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539208/rowids-resetting-in-jqgrid-how-to-prevent-it).

The solution accepted there is to use primary key but I don't have primary key for my rows. Is there a way to force jqgrid to have unique row Ids upon sorting, changing pages Or deleting rows ?

The issue I have is if I delete a say row 2 from a grids with 5 rows the rowid for 3 is set to 2, row4 to 3...etc. I want my rows to be unique Ids and I want that to be generated in the client side

For more info: My grid is client side paged and sorted.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/141/) link to the sample data of my grid.

```
testRow = function()
{
   var row2correct =   $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData', 2);//  {meterid:2, DocGroupName: "name2", DocList: "list2", Mandatory: "No"};

   var row6wong =   $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData', 6);// is empty but i was expecting {meterid:4, DocGroupName: "name6", DocList: "ggg", Mandatory: "Yes"}

}
            var mydata = [
                    {meterid:1 , metername: "name1", DocList: "list1", Mandatory: "Yes"},
                    {meterid:2, metername: "name2", DocList: "list2", Mandatory: "No"},
                    {meterid:1, metername: "name3", DocList: "list3", Mandatory: "No"},
                    {meterid:3, metername: "name4", DocList: "list4", Mandatory: "Yes"},
                     {meterid:4, metername: "name5", DocList: "list5", Mandatory: "Yes"},
                      {meterid:4, metername: "name6", DocList: "ggg", Mandatory: "Yes"},
                ];
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                height: "auto",
              colNames: ['Meterid', 'metername','Document Name','No of Mandatory'],
                colModel :[
                    {name:'meterid', index:'meterid', width:55},
                    {name:'metername', index:'metername', width:90},
                    {name:'DocList', index:'DocList', width:90, editable: true },                  {name:'Mandatory', index:'Mandatory', width:90, editable: true}                
                ],
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum:4,
                rowList:[4,8,30],
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true
            });
```

Comment: Typical reason of your problem: you **filled** the data in the wrong way without specifying the unique id of every item of input data. You should append the text of your question with example of the data which you use to fill the grid (2-3 rows would be enough) and JavaScript code which you use to create jqGrid. Moreover it's important to know which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: @Oleg I just edited my question with a link to jsfiddle and sample code. The reason I don't have a primary key is because my rows key is a composite key so I am not able to set key:true in any one of the columns. Keep in mind this is a sample I created for the sake of this question my real one is so complicated and the data is created in mvc.

Comment: Every row of jqGrid **must** have an unique id attribute (see [the picture](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal)). **Which** composite key is unique in the data? Why you use `index:'id'` for the column with `name:'meterid'`? You can compose `id` property for every item of input data. The current input data are not so good because all other properties with exception `meterid` are **editable**. It's very bad to have editable id. Do you use `datatype: 'xml'` in your original demo? Do you have native XML data or you serialize the data as XML instead of JSON?

Comment: Sorry it was by mistake I did those. Coz I created this as a quick sample. My composite key is meterid and metername. and both are not editable.I fixed the code and the jsfiddle link to reflect that.

Comment: your demo still have many errors: `id="pager"` will be used multiple times in HTML markup, `testRow` and `currentRow` are undefined, the option `sortname: 'idcustomers'` seems be wrong because there are no column with the name `idcustomers`, `"use strict";` have to be *the first line* to work. It's better to *remove* all unneeded `index` properties from `colModel`. I'm not sure what you want to do in `afterSaveCell`. To clear content of `DocList` column you can use `$(this).jqGrid("setCell", rowid, 'DocList');`, but `if (name=='DocGroupName') {` should be `if (name === 'metername') {`...

Comment: You can add `for (i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) { mydata[i].id = String(mydata[i].meterid) + "_" + mydata[i].metername; }` before usage of `mydata` as the value of `data` parameter. It should fix your main problem. If you load the data from the server then you can assign `id` on the server side or to use `beforeProcessing` callback to modified the data returned from the server *before* the data will be processed by jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks that is what I ended up doing at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```js
var i, l = mydata.length, item;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    item = mydata[i];
    item.id = String(item.meterid) + "_" + item.metername;
}
```

before usage of `mydata` as the value of data parameter. It should fix your main problem. If you load the data from the server then you can assign id on the server side or to use `beforeProcessing` callback to modified the data returned from the server before the data will be processed by jqGrid.